# Laptop won't boot after fresh install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, kubuntu

I have an Acer Aspire E5-511 laptop. I am trying to install Ubuntu or Kubuntu, but after I do the updates it won't boot. It boots to a black screen with this message and the fan make noise:

```
[    2.448950] Problem loading UEFI: db X.509 certificate (-65)  
[    2.449012] Problem loading UEFI: db X.509 certificate (-65)  
[    2.449111] Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000000e
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your secure boot.Restart your system and enter BIOS mode and then disable secure boot.

To do so you can follow [How to disable Secure Boot in BIOS](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Support/FAQ/3001)?

Comment: secure boot is disabled

Comment: Disabling secure boot didn't resolve the issue. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to install Ubuntu 20.04, and it seems to have happened because *Secure Boot* was enabled during installation.

So the newly created `.efi` file had to be added as trusted in BIOS.

Got the solution [from here on it's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

In legacy BIOS compatibility mode the UEFI firmware functions as a standard BIOS instead of UEFI firmware, which improves compatibility with operating systems that weren't designed with UEFI in mind.

Enter the BIOS/UEFI setup utility when the computer is starting, disable Secure Boot, and [enable Legacy/CSM boot mode](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/disable-UEFI-enable-legacy-support.html).

[image]
<sup>**disable Secure Boot**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**enable Legacy/CSM boot mode**</sup>

<sup>[source](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/disable-UEFI-enable-legacy-support.html)</sup>

Comment: There is only "UEFI" option in Aspire ES1-533