# Ubuntu kernel is not loading on laptop

Tags: grub2, kernel

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop with `grub2` boot loader. Last night I tried to go to Ubuntu, but this error is appeared.

laptop model : lenovo ideapad 510-15ikb

[image]

The `/sdb6` is the Ubuntu root partition on my SSD drive and I have a Toshiba HDD too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop won't boot after fresh install Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105559/laptop-wont-boot-after-fresh-install-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I tried that solution but it's not working

Comment: **Closer Voters** I retracted my close vote duplicate because OP tried it and it doesn't solve the problem.